# Вставка 2х запросов в 1 таблицу

Tags: sql-server, sql

Допустим таблица

```
create table tabl1
(
 a int,
 b int
);
```

и 2 запроса

```
select 1 from tabl2;    
select 2 from tabl3;
```

как вставить данные из 2х запросов в `tabl1`, что бы она имела вид  как на картинке?

[image: 123]

Comment: @Владислав Сергеевич странный вопрос. Вставить столько строк с A=1, сколько записей в tabl2, и столько строк с B=2, сколько записей в tabl3. Это могут быть одни и те же строки? Или это должны быть одни и те же строки? А если их разное количество?

Comment: это просто пример, интересна была сама реализация, да бы применить в работе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into table
with a as (
select 1 as val from dual
),
b as (
select 2 as val from dual
)
select a.val as A, b.val as B from a, b
```

Comment: спасибо, как-то не додумался сам)